# How can I return key-value pairs from a function in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, key-value

I am implementing a C# function.
I need to get the values from the function to the form.

```
public void GetRoles(string strGetRoles)
{
    string keyObj;
    string valueObj;
    var parseTree = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(strGetRoles);

    foreach (var prop in parseTree.Properties())
    {
        dynamic propValue = prop.Value;
        if (prop.Name == "roles" && prop.Value.HasValues)
        {
            foreach (var proval in propValue)
            {
                keyObj = (string)proval.Name;
                valueObj = (string)proval.Value;                                               
            }
        }
        else if (prop.Name == "groups" && prop.Value.HasValues)
        {
            foreach (var proval in propValue)
            {
                keyObj = (string)proval.Name;
                valueObj = (string)proval.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`strGetRoles` is the response string I get after fetching JSON API.
The `prop.Value` I get is:
{"roles": {"3": "Reseller","2": "Admin end user"},"groups": []}

Now I want to call this function and get each value in an object or string array.

How do I return these key-value pairs?

Comment: How about using `Dictionary`?

Comment: Return a Tuple, use the out keyword for the parameters or return a dictionary

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can return [KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2) like this:

```
return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(key,value);
```

or use [`Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple):

```
return Tuple.Create(key,value);
```

if you have more than one KeyValuePair to return use Dictionary.
Read more about [when to use Tuple vs KeyValuePair](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107889/when-should-i-use-a-2-property-class-over-a-pre-built-structure-like-a-keyvaluep).
In short using Tuple is better idea because of it's better performance.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Tuple<T1, T2>`.

```
public Tuple<string, string> GetRoles(string strGetRoles)
{
    //...
    return Tuple.Create(key, value);
}
```

If you have more than one key-value pair, then return a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead.